# How to initialize a var defined in HTML in Angular unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have a var declared in a component.ts file
`declare var foo`
this var is defined in index.html as `<script>var foo = {}</script>`

How can I mimic the declaration of index.html in Angular unit test

I am running a simple unit test to expect component to be truthy,
`beforeEach(() => { fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent); component= fixture.componentInstance; fixture.detectChanges(); } it("should create", () => { expect(component).toBeTruthy; }) )`

But I get the error `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a script and add it to the `angular.json`

Your block should look similar to

```json
 "test": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
  "options": {
    "main": "src/test.ts",    
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
    "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
    "styles": ["src/assets/style/main.scss"],
    "scripts": [/* your script here */]
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any other way to just change the test case like inject html ?

Comment: there may be, but not that i know of